# How can i find the best GARCH (p,q) in this serie?

Tags: econometrics, time-series

[image: Returns of stocks]

Of course the first step would be to make the first difference of the series, because there's obviusly a unit root.
Can someone offer a solution to find the best Garch? I would be pleased to send the data. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This would better fit [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).